# Google App Engine: Python 2.5 and Python 2.7 on Win 7(64 bit)

Tags: python, google-app-engine, sdk

I am on Win 7(64 bits) and I would like to play with Google App Engine. I downloaded latest version of "Google App Engine SDK for Python" from https://developers.google.com/appengine/downloads and I am going to install it.

I know I need toinstall Python 2.5 and 2.7 first.

My questions:

1. Can I install both Python versions on the same computer?
2. I want to use either Python 2.5 or 2.7 **AUTOMATICALLY** based on the `app.yaml` configure line: `runtime: python` or `runtime: python27`

By **AUTOMATICALLY**, I mean I dont have to choose the Python Version everytime I run an application in `Google App Engine -> Edit (Tab) -> Preferences -> Python Path`

Comment: If you're not working with an already-existing legacy app, there's really no reason to use the 2.5 runtime at all. It may not be officially deprecated, but the 2.7 runtime is recommended for a good reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes, you can install multiple python versions on your computer without problems.
2. Python 2.7 is backwards compatible with 2.5. Code that works on 2.5 will work on 2.7 just fine. Use the Python 2.7 binary in your SDK, switch all apps to the `python27` runtime and don't look back. There is no need to switch back and forth.